# Are FB Instant Articles performance indicators tracked with Google Analytics true?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, facebook-graph

I measure Instant Articles with Google Analytics for quiet a while now and doubt the results of some of the metrics recorded.

For instant articles the *average time on page* is *00:03:30* where normal mobile traffic from facebook is only about *00:01:00*. Given that instant articles are short and simple that strikes me as to high. Also *bounce rate* is about *90%* which leaves a remainder of *10%* to calculate the *average time on page*; rather unreliable.

I also queried facebooks aggregated Instant Articles API and the average time is very different with about *00:01:20*.

Did you experience similar results? Do you have any explanation for the stated data or an alternative idea on how to measure performance reliably and comparsion with regular mobile Facebook traffic in mind?

PS: All information are backed by data from round about half a year.

Comment: Have you implemented Google Analytics events for scrolling yet?   Sending  GA data when the user scrolls down the page to read the article is a great way to track how long users actually spend on your pages.

Comment: I didn't, but I will in the near future. I'd still be happy to understand the discrepancy beteween data collected by GA and FB Insights. Built in time based metrics seem unreliable in genera when it comes to GA.

Comment: By default GA measures time between the first page load and the start of the last page load.   One page sessions have zero time.     The only way to improve it is to implement events that send GA information as users use your pages.

Comment: I'm aware of the calculations as stated in Google's documentation, I'm still in doubt about the actual numbers though. That's why I'm looking for a way to assess the numbers I see. If there was a way to debug the tracking itself, that would be very helpful.